# Could UTF-8 cause a decryption error in my C script but not in the Python one?

Tags: python, c, openssl

I'm trying to create a C version of a Python [Chrome Password Recoverer](https://github.com/ohyicong/decrypt-chrome-passwords/blob/main/decrypt_chrome_password.py) as my first project.
I've gotten long with small problems, but I just can't figure this one. When I try and run the Python version of the script like this:

```
def decrypt_payload(cipher, payload):
    return cipher.decrypt(payload)

def generate_cipher(aes_key, iv):
    return AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)

def decrypt_password(ciphertext, secret_key):
    try:
        #(3-a) Initialisation vector for AES decryption
        print("Original Password: ", ciphertext)
        initialisation_vector = ciphertext[3:15]
        print("Initialization vector: ", initialisation_vector)
        #(3-b) Get encrypted password by removing suffix bytes (last 16 bits)
        #Encrypted password is 192 bits
        encrypted_password = ciphertext[15:-16]
        print("Encrypted_password: ", encrypted_password)
        print("AES key: ", secret_key)
        #(4) Build the cipher to decrypt the ciphertext
        cipher = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_GCM, initialisation_vector)
        decrypted_pass = decrypt_payload(cipher, encrypted_password)
        decrypted_pass = decrypted_pass.decode()
        print("Decrypted Password: ", decrypted_pass)
        sys.exit()
        return decrypted_pass
    except Exception as e:
        print("%s"%str(e))
        print("[ERR] Unable to decrypt, Chrome version <80 not supported. Please check.")
        return ""
```

I get the "correct" output I'm guessing because it decoded the password right:

```c
Original Password:  b'v10\xb5\xee\n\xa4k\xd5\xc8@\xca\xcfWn\xcd\xcb\xbb\x16\x11gp\x81\xbf\x0e\xaf4:\xf3IJk4>\xee#\x1cl\x1c'
Initialization vector:  b'\xb5\xee\n\xa4k\xd5\xc8@\xca\xcfWn'
Encrypted_password:  b'\xcd\xcb\xbb\x16\x11gp\x81'
AES key:  b'\xa7\x91%\r08\xe0\xaf\x96\xd65i\x98;\xbb\x0c\xcb\xf4\tH\x90\xa3\x90U\xb6#\xb7!\x95R1\xbc'
Decrypted Password:  H***** (Right Password)
```

But when I run this my own C version:

```
void decryptPassword(char* encPass)
{
    // 12 byte initialization vector
    unsigned char initialization_vector[12];
    memcpy(initialization_vector, encPass + 3, 12);
    printf("Initialization vector: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        printf("\\x%02x", initialization_vector[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Get encrypted password
    int encrypted_len = strlen(encPass) - 31;
    unsigned char encrypted_password[encrypted_len];
    memcpy(encrypted_password, encPass + 15, encrypted_len);
    printf("Encrypted_password: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < encrypted_len; i++) {
        printf("\\x%02x", encrypted_password[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");


    printf("AES key: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printf("\\x%02x", AESkey[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len;
    unsigned char plaintext[32];
    unsigned char tag[16];
    AES_KEY aes_key;
    if (AES_set_decrypt_key(AESkey, 256, &aes_key) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not set decryption key.");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) {
        handleErrors();
    }
    if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        handleErrors();
    }
    if (1 != EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, 12, NULL)) {
        handleErrors();
    }
    if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, AESkey, initialization_vector)) {
        handleErrors();
    }
    if (1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, NULL, &len, encPass + 15, encrypted_len)) {
        handleErrors();
    }
    if (1 != EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, 16, encPass + 15 + encrypted_len)) {
        handleErrors();
    }
    if (1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext, &len)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Decryption failed.");
        exit(1);
    }
    plaintext_len = len;
    if (1 != EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, 16, tag)) {
        handleErrors();
    }
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    printf("decrypted_password: %s\n", plaintext);
}
```

I get this output:

```c
Original Password: \x76\x31\x30\xb5\xee\x0a\xa4\x6b\xd5\xc8\x40\xca\xcf\x57\x6e\xcd\xcb\xbb\x16\x11\x67\x70\x81\xbf\x0e\xaf\x34\x3a\xf3\x49\x4a\x6b\x34\x3e\xee\x23\x1c\x6c\x1c
Initialization vector: \xb5\xee\x0a\xa4\x6b\xd5\xc8\x40\xca\xcf\x57\x6e
Encrypted_password: \xcd\xcb\xbb\x16\x11\x67\x70\x81
AES key: \xa7\x91\x25\x0d\x30\x38\xe0\xaf\x96\xd6\x35\x69\x98\x3b\xbb\x0c\xcb\xf4\x09\x48\x90\xa3\x90\x55\xb6\x23\xb7\x21\x95\x52\x31\xbc
Decryption failed.
```

So the text is very similar because the Python just UTF-8 encodes characters it can, but yet this ends up in a "Decryption failed." and ChatGPT said "1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext, &len))" usually means some key or value is wrong, so is the problem in the format like I'm thinking, or maybe in the way of the AES GCM decrypting?

I already tried to try and change back the bytes that Python changed to utf-8, but I don't understand how did Python change "\xbc" just into "\xb". I also tried different ways of doing the AES GCM decryption, such as using other libraries which included gcm.h.

I was also at one point thinking of making a function that takes in the bytes and tries to match/change them into UTF-8 characters.

Here Is a more clarified version of the differences:

> Right Key:                      \xa7\x91%\r08\xe0\xaf\x96\xd65i\x98;\xbb\x0c\xcb\xf4\tH\x90\xa3\x90U\xb6#\xb7!\x95R1\xb
>
> The Key my C script got:        \xa7\x91\x25\x0d\x30\x38\xe0\xaf\x96\xd6\x35\x69\x98\x3b\xbb\x0c\xcb\xf4\x09\x48\x90\xa3\x90\x55\xb6\x23\xb7\x21\x95\x52\x31\xbc

> Right Ciphertext:               \xcd\xcb\xbb\x16\x11gp\x81
>
> The Ciphertext my C script got: \xcd\xcb\xbb\x16\x11\x67\x70\x81

> Right IV:                       \xb5\xee\n\xa4k\xd5\xc8@\xca\xcfWn
>
> The IV my C script got:         \xb5\xee\x0a\xa4\x6b\xd5\xc8\x40\xca\xcf\x57\x6e

Also would appreciate other advice for C because I just started C 2 months ago!

Comment: `int encrypted_len = strlen(encPass)` looks dodgy.  If the encrypted password has _null characters_ in it, the length will be amiss.  For handling binary data, best to avoid `str...()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in the output between the two in terms of bytes.  What you're seeing is a printing difference.

Python is using mixed printing, where printable characters are printed directly, control characters are printed with single character backslash escapes, and other characters are hex encoded.

In contrast, the C code is printing *all* characters with hex escapes.

For example, for the third and fourth characters, the C code is printing the hex code \x25 and \x0d.  These are the ASCII codes for the `%` character and a carriage return respectively.  The Python code is printing a literal `%` followed by `\r` which is the escape code for a carriage return.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! That's what I thought, so the problem is most probably in the way I'm trying to use AES GCM to decrypt the encrypted text?